# JSON formatting for highlighting field or row red when after due date

Tags: office-365

I'm looking to format a "due date" column, to look at that date, and if the current date is after it, then the row or field is highlighted red.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found it on Microsofts web link!

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

```
{

   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "style": {
      "color": {
         "operator": "?",
         "operands": [
            {
               "operator": "<=",
               "operands": [
                  "[$DueDate]",
                  "@now"
               ]
            },
            "#ff0000",
            ""
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

This section you'll have to look out for:
"If you have spaces in the field name, those are defined as *x0020*. For example, a field named "Due Date" should be referenced as $Due_x0020_Date."